# Why is my use of jQuery filter() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sort some events by date, genre and venue. When a checkbox or a date from the calendar is clicked, I want to only be shown events for that date and those checkboxex. For example, if I choose **21** from **calendar**, **classical** from genre checkboxes and **Lucas theatre** from venue checkbox, I want it to show me only the events on 21st which are in Lucas and are classical. And I want it to hide everything else.

However, my filter() to  show only the selected stuff seems to not be working. Am I wrong on the concept of the filter() or my use of it, or isthe problem something else?

This is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('input').attr('checked', false);

    $('label.check').click(function(){
            if( $(this).find('input').is(':checked') ){
                $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
                $(this).removeClass('checked');
            } else {
                $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
                $(this).addClass('checked');
            }

            $(this).find('input').trigger('change');

            return false;
        });

    $('label.check, .calendar a').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        filtering();
        return false;
    });

    function filtering(){
        var values = {}
        $('.search-options').each(function(){

            var attr_name = $(this).attr('name');
            var check_value = $(this).find('input:checked');
            var date_text = $(this).find('.calendar a.active');

            values[attr_name] = [];

            check_value.each(function(){
                values[attr_name].push('' + attr_name + '="' + $(this).val() + '"');
            });

            date_text.each(function(){
                values[attr_name].push('' + attr_name + '="' + $(this).text() + '"');
            });
        })

        for ( var i in values ){

            var joined = values[i].join()
            var match = $('.widget.left').filter(joined);
            match.show()
            console.log( match );
        };
    };
});
```

This is my HTML it is about:

```
   <div class="dd">
       <div class="concerts check-group">
           <form action="" method="post">
               <div class="search-options left" name="date">
                    <h3>Select Dates</h3>
                    <div class="calendar-title">
                        <h4>March &amp; April 2013</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calendar">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th>s</th>
                                <th>m</th>
                                <th>t</th>
                                <th>w</th>
                                <th>t</th>
                                <th>f</th>
                                <th>s</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="disabled">17</td>
                                <td class="disabled">18</td>
                                <td class="disabled">19</td>
                                <td class="disabled">20</td>
                                <td><a href="#">21</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">22</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">23</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#">24</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">25</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">26</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">27</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">28</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">29</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">30</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#">31</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">4</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#">6</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="search-options left" name="genre">
                    <h3>genre</h3>
                    <div class="labels genre-vals">
                        <label class="check">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield all-check" value="all" checked="checked" />
                            All genres
                        </label>
                        <label class="check">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="jazz-and-blues" checked="checked" />
                            jazz &amp; Blues
                        </label>
                        <label class="check">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="classical" checked="checked" />
                            Classical
                        </label>
                        <label class="check">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="americana" checked="checked" />
                            Americana
                        </label>
                        <label class="check">
                            <span></span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="world-music" checked="checked" />
                            World Music
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="search-options wide right venue-vals" name="venue">
                    <h3>venues</h3>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="labels">
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield all-check" value="all" checked="checked" />
                                All venues
                            </label>
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="telfair" checked="checked" />
                                Telfair Academy of Arts &amp; Science
                            </label>
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="lucas" checked="checked" />
                                Lucas Theatre for the Arts
                            </label>
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="trustees" checked="checked" />
                                Trustees Theater
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="labels">
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="charles" checked="checked" />
                                Charles H. Morris Center
                            </label>
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="trinity" checked="checked" />
                                Trinity United Methodist Church
                            </label>
                            <label class="check">
                                <span></span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkfield" value="ships" checked="checked" />
                                Ships of the Sea North Garden
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!-- end dropdown -->

    <!-- widgets -->
    <div class="events result-list">
        <div class="widget left" date="22" genre="classical" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="22" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="lucas">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="22" genre="americana" venue="charles">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="23" genre="world-music" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="23" genre="classical" venue="trustees">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="24" genre="americana" venue="ships">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="24" genre="classical" venue="lucas">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="25" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="trinity">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="26" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="charles">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="26" genre="classical" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="26" genre="world-music" venue="charles">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="27" genre="americana" venue="trinity">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="27" genre="classical" venue="lucas">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="28" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="ships">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="28" genre="classical" venue="ships">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="29" genre="world-music" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="29" genre="americana" venue="trustees">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="30" genre="classical" venue="trustees">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="30" genre="world-music" venue="charles">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="31" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="lucas">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="31" genre="world-music" venue="trustees">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="1" genre="classical" venue="ships">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="2" genre="classical" venue="lucas">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="2" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="trinity">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="widget left" date="3" genre="classical" venue="charles">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="4" genre="jazz-and-blues" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="5" genre="classical" venue="telfair">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget left" date="6" genre="americana" venue="ships">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="date">THUR 3/21</span>
                <img src="css/images/photo05.jpg" alt="" id="image1" />
            </a>
            <div class="widget-cnt">
                <h4><a href="#">Noon30: sweet singing harmony harmoneers</a></h4>
                <p>12:30 pm | Charles H. Morris Center</p>
                <p>Carrying forth the tradition of jubilee gospel greats the Fairfield Four and the Golden Gate Quartet,...</p>
                <div class="widget-links">
                    <a href="#">read more</a>
                    <a href="#">buy tickets</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build an attribute selector? Then you forgot the square brackets.

Comment: I can't see the "*…and hide everything else*" in your code

Comment: In this shape of the code everything is hidden and I want to show the filtered events only (when it starts working I fix it as I want)... and for the attr selector did you ment that the push-es are wrong while I am creating the attributes ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that it should be `push('[' + attr_name + '="' + value + '"]')` if you really are targeting an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: omg .. yes that was one of the mistakes ... now it shows results, but not filtered. It is showing everything I have 'clicked'.

Comment: I think it filters them, but combining the single `value` selectors with OR instead of AND since you select and show everything that matches one for every of them

Comment: Hmm now I am thinking it is because when I "unclick" the common visible events are not hiding. I have to figure that and after that must be the new filtering. It has to be somethink like this.

Comment: Nope .. I figured it out. I just put $('.widget.left:visible').hide() before the loop. Now the 'unclick' works, but the filter proccess still doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change attribute selector as **Bergi** mentioned and change this code (OR filtering):

```
    widgets.hide();
    for ( var i in values ){
        var joined = values[i].join();
        var match = widgets.filter(joined);
        match.show();
    };
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tZyWa/

OR (AND filtering):

```
    widgets.hide();
    var match = widgets;
    for ( var i in values ){
        var joined = values[i].join();
        match = match.filter(joined);
    };
    match.show();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tZyWa/1/

Comment: `values` is an object of arrays, so he enumerates it? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you are absolutely right. Post was updated.

Comment: It worked with this AND. Thank you very much. Now I need to make this filter on 'unclick'. Now if I have 26 date clicked and chek the "classical", when I uncheck "classical" everything disappear. events on 26th are not shown too.

Comment: @ПанайотТолев Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tZyWa/2/